# XML data extraction in python

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML file like the following:

```
<AreaModel>
    ...
    <RecipePhase>
        <UniqueName>PHASE1</UniqueName>
        ...
        <NumberOfParameterTags>7</NumberOfParameterTags>
        ...
        <DefaultRecipeParameter>
            <Name>PARAM1</Name>
            ----
        </DefaultRecipeParameter>
        <DefaultRecipeParameter>
            <Name>PARAM2</Name>
            ----
        </DefaultRecipeParameter>
        <DefaultRecipeParameter>
            <Name>PARAM3</Name>
            ----
        </DefaultRecipeParameter>
    </RecipePhase>
    <RecipePhase>
    ....
    </RecipePhase>
</AreaModel>
```

I would like to read this file in sequential order and generate different list. One for the texts of `UniqueName` `TAGs` and a list of lists containing for each list the set of texts for tag Name under each `RecipePhase` element.

For example, I might have 10 `RecipePhase` elements, each one with TAG `UniqueName` and each one containing a different set of children with tag `DefaultRecipeParameter`.

How can I take into account when I enter into `RecipePhase` and when I go out of the element during parsing?

I am trying ElementTree but I am not able to find a solution.

cheers,
m

Answer (score 0):

You can use xml python module: 
See my example:

```
from xml.dom import minidom as dom
import urllib2

def fetchPage(url):
    a = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    return ''.join(a.readlines())

def extract(page):
    a = dom.parseString(page)

    item = a.getElementsByTagName('Rate')

    for i in item:
        if i.hasChildNodes() == True:
                print i.getAttribute('currency')+"-"+ i.firstChild.nodeValue

if __name__=='__main__':
    page = fetchPage("http://www.bnro.ro/nbrfxrates.xml")
    extract(page)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved partially my problem with the following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('control_strategies.axml')
root = tree.getroot()

phases=[]

for recipephase in root.findall('./RecipePhase/UniqueName'):
    phases.append(recipephase.text)

n_elem = len(phases)

param=[[] for _ in range(n_elem)]

i = 0

for recipephase in root.findall('./RecipePhase'):

    for defparam in recipephase.findall('./DefaultRecipeParameter'):

        for paramname in defparam.findall('./Name'):
            param[i].append(paramname.text)
    i = i + 1
```